# bash IF not matching variable that contains regex numbers

Tags: regex, bash, if-statement

DPHPV = /usr/local/nginx/conf/php81-remi.conf;

I am unable to figure out how to match a string that contains any 2 digits:

```
if [[ "$DPHPV" =~ *"php[:digit:][:digit:]-remi.conf"* ]]
```

Comment: If you are trying to match files with names like `php53-remi.conf` then one way to do it is `if [[ $DPHPV == php[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]-remi.conf ]]`.

Comment: Use: `[[ "$DPHPV" =~ php[0-9][0-9]-remi.conf ]]`

Comment: The whole purpose of quoting in Bash is to suppress the special significance that certain characters or character sequences would otherwise have, such as for globbing.

Comment: You're also mixing syntax for globbing, by using `*`, but `=~` requires regular expressions, where the equivalent would be `.*`. Regexes alo aren't anchored, so the `*`/`.*` can just be skipped. Glob expressions (`==`/`=` instead of `=~`) require matching the entire string, so there you would need the `*`

Comment: The part of the rhs of the `=~` , which is written between quotes, is interpreted as a literal match, not as a regular expression. Further, the lone `*` in front of the regex does not have any meaning as regex. You can see it when doing i.e. a `[[ x =~ * ]]`, which does not match.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the right regex here as `*` is a quantifier in regex, not a placeholder for any text.

Actually, you do not need a regex, you may use a mere glob pattern like

```bash
if [[ "$DPHPV" == *php[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]-remi.conf ]]
```

**Note**

- `==` - enables glob matching
- `*php[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]-remi.conf` - matches any text with `*`, then matches `php`, then two digits (note that the POSIX character classes must be used inside bracket expressions), and then `-rem.conf` at the end of string.
  See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/6pdYAx):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
DPHPV='/usr/local/nginx/conf/php81-remi.conf'
if [[ "$DPHPV" == *php[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]-remi.conf ]]; then
    echo yes;
else
    echo no;
fi
```

Output: `yes`.